# delete cookies / localStorage / sessionStorage / cache from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently linking a link to a page on my website. When the link is clicked, an external page of the government is immediately loaded in which the user must authenticate by a form. by doing so it redirects according to the attribute `ReturnUrl`.

```
<a href="https://xxx.gov.co/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/SignIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=http:localhost:3000/redirect">go to autenticate</a>
```

Once authenticated, if I try to click on the link, I can not authenticate anymore and it redirects me instantly. I'm trying to close the session to authenticate again. but I am unable to access that form, unless from google chrome delete the cache completely. also observe from google chrome cookies, sessionStorage, localStorage and I do not find that there is something. What I can do?

What can I do so that when I click again on the hyperlink it forces me to authenticate again and does not redirect me to my page ?. I need log out

Comment: @baao What can I do so that when I click again on the hyperlink it forces me to authenticate again and does not redirect me to my page?

Comment: Log out manually or create another link that points to their log out and click that first

Comment: @baao I do not understand you. or I do not know how to do it.